# POSTGRESQL and Django app: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, postgresql, django

I am running a django app with postgresql, nginx and gunicorn. I have a script where data is pulled from one table in the DB, modified and then needs to replace the existing data in that one table. In the same script, a few tables are also being updated.

When runnning the script, it always results in `502 Bad Gateway` because the server times out because of something in the script. Being fairly new the topic, I am struggling to figure out what is going on with the following error.

I only have the following log to work with from postgres:

```
2020-08-22 14:57:59 UTC::@:[8228]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-22 14:57:59 UTC::@:[8228]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=70182 kB
2020-08-22 14:58:50 UTC:address-ip(45726):pierre@dbexostock:[25618]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2020-08-22 14:58:50 UTC:address-ip(45724):pierre@dbexostock:[25617]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

I think the issue is inside of the connections to the database in the script:

```
#connect to db
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@amazon.host.west',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

#access the data in the historical_data table 
conn = engine.connect()
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
histoo = sqlalchemy.Table('uploadfiles_historical_data', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = sqlalchemy.select([histoo])
resultproxy = conn.execute(query)
        
        
result_set = resultproxy.fetchall()

#update the historical table 
histo = histo2.head(0).to_sql('uploadfiles_histoo', engine, if_exists='replace')
cur = conn.cursor()
output = io.StringIO()
histo2.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, encoding='utf8')
output.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(output,'uploadfiles_histoo')
conn.commit()

#update other tables (example)
itemmdb = df559.to_sql('dashboard_item', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

I am really confused and been banging my head on this problem for a while and nothing seem to be working. Hoping that someone could see where I am messing up.

Comment: Check your application's logs.

Comment: my application log does not tell me anything is wrong. but obviously there is something wrong!